# how to use `__rdtsc` properly in linux x86 gcc

Tags: linux, gcc, rdtsc

In linux, the gcc compiler has the intrinsic function `__rdtsc` to measure the cpu cycles. So I don't need to use inline asm code, which I am not familiar with.

On the other hand, when reading posts about the asm code, I saw people saying that `rdtsc` instruction should be used in combination with `cpuid` or other fences to flush the pipeline, like [this one](https://www.strchr.com/performance_measurements_with_rdtsc).

My question is: without using `asm` code, what is the proper way to flush the pipeline for linux x64 in order to measure cycles correctly?

Moreover, there is also `__rdtscp`. Does this function already flushed the pipeline so it can be used to replace the `flush + __rdtsc`?